# The Interesting bash behaviour

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Why does this command (creating an empty folder, changing to it, touching a file, calling `ls` and then `cat`ing it), display two files?

```
root@ubuntu:~# mkdir a ; cd a ; touch b ; ls > c ; cat c
b
c
```

I believe that I should only get "b".

Comment: @ElliottFrisch "Could you please explain why"

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The question seems to be *"Why does this command display two files?"*. I edited the post to close the paranthesis appropriately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you redirect the output of `ls` to the file `c`, it's a chicken and egg problem:

If `c` would not be created upfront, that would mean the shell would need to store the output in a buffer and (in the end) write that buffer to the file.

Since this is not the best approach in many cases (because of memory management, management of failure for commands that get interrupted before completion, etc.), the file gets created upfront.

Thus, the standard output for the command can be replaced with the newly created file and the command output can be *streamed* to that file.

Answer (score 3):

The redirection of standard output for the command

```
ls > c
```

Creates the file handle for `c` before the command `ls` executes. The `touch b` (and visibility of `b` are a red-herring). For example,

```
mkdir t ; cd t ; ls > a ; cat a
```

Will display `a` (**because** the `>` creates the `a` before `ls` is [`exec`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_%28computing%29#Unix.2C_POSIX.2C_and_other_multitasking_systems)d).

Answer (score 1):

The file is created (or truncated) so the output of `ls` can be redirected to it.

Hence, `ls` sees the file.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding that the output of `ls` is being redirected to a file c, we need to look at the procedure the shell uses to execute such command.

When the shell process a command line (very simplified):

1. Divides the line into tokens (usually at spaces).
2. Interprets all tokens (which are commands, arguments, redirections).
3. Sets up the structure of input and output, including any redirections.
4. Execute the command, sending its output to the correct place.

As the output needs to be set at step 3, any file that will receive output, must exist, or be created if it does not exist.

Then, by the time the command (ls in this case) is executed, the file (c in this case) must already exist to receive the command output.

It is therefore correct to see the two files listed in the content of the file c.